# Unable to compute GLSL shader 16.04 Panda3D game engine

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm attempting to install the Panda3d Render Pipeline on an integrated intel gpu - Intel Ivybridge Mobile. Running Ubuntu 16.04

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Render Pipeline Setup 1.3

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


[ 01 ]  Checking Panda3D Modules


[ 02 ]  Checking requirements ..
    Running script: data/setup/check_requirements.py


The C++ modules of the pipeline are faster and produce better 
results, but we will have to compile them. As alternative, 
a Python fallback is used, which is slower and produces worse 
results. Also some plugins only partially work with the python 
fallback (e.g. PSSM). Do you want to compile the C++ modules? (y/n): y


[ 03 ]  Downloading the module builder ...
    Running script: rpcore/native/update_module_builder.py
    Downloading:   0.00  B/s |                               |  0%   ETA:  --:--:-- Downloading:  92.82 GB/s |################################|100%   Time: 0:00:00


[ 04 ]  Building the native code .. (This might take a while!)
    Running script: rpcore/native/build.py


[ 05 ]  Generating .txo files ...
    Running script: data/generate_txo_files.py


[ 06 ]  Filtering default cubemap ..
    Running script: data/default_cubemap/filter.py
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): Could not create a GLSL compute shader.
Assertion failed: do_has_ram_mipmap_image(cdata, n) at line 4948 of panda/src/gobj/texture.cxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 105, in <module>
    Application()
  File "filter.py", line 93, in __init__
    dest_cubemap.write(join(filter_dir, "{}-#.png".format(mipmap)), 0, 0, True, False)
AssertionError: do_has_ram_mipmap_image(cdata, n) at line 4948 of panda/src/gobj/texture.cxx
Failed to execute 'filter.py'
Output: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-B', 'filter.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1 
 Filtering mipmap 0
 Extracting data ..
 Writing data ..


It seems the setup failed, do you want to open the troubleshooting page for this step? (y/n):  n

Setup failed:    Python script didn't return properly!

Please fix the above errors and then restart the setup.
```

You'll notice the issues lie with this line:

```
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): Could not create a GLSL compute shader.
```

Obviously a graphics issue. Apparently shader issues with integrated intel graphics are commonplace, especially with earlier versions (Intel Celeron 1005M here).
I've tried reinstalling drivers, updating and removing them, to no avail.

I'm using Panda 1.10 with the latest version of render pipeline.

Is this an issue with drivers? Or kernel support for glsl?

Comment: I found myself in the same situation. Also 16.04 and Intel Ivybridge graphics. Did you manage to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is because the CPU is too old to support versions of GPL newer than v3. Panda3D requires openGL 4.x I think, or it did at the time. The onboard GPU is basically unable to compute the necessary calculations to run the engine. You're probably going to need to upgrade your system

Comment: As turned out all I needed to do is add appropriate repository and run sudo apt-get update. I missed that. After that new updates had been installed and everything's been okay ever since. Glad I didn't have to butcher my computer.

Comment: @MarkAlexa curious. What CPU are you using?

Comment: It's Intel Core i7 3.1GHz (8 cores)

Comment: @MarkAlexa well that makes sense then ;D